# Grouping Query Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 3 classes:

```
Class 1:
public IEnumerable<double> Values;
public Class2 class2Instance;

Class2:
public string Name;
public Class3 class3Instance;

Class3:
public long Id;
public string Name;
```

Now I have got a huge collection of `Class1`, something like an `IEnumerable<Class1>`, and I have the `Class3` Id. How can I use an efficient LINQ query to get all `Class1` instances which are relevant to `Class2` which matches with `Class1` ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you've *only* got a sequence of them, you've got to go through all of them:

```
var matches = collection.Where(x => x.class2Instance.class3Instance.Id == id);
```

If you need to do this regularly, you may want to build a `Dictionary<long, Class1>` instead.

(I'm assuming that neither `class2Instance` nor `class3Instance` can be null. If they can, you'll need to use code like Aducci's.)

Comment: I think you might need `class2Instance.class3Instance.id`

Answer (score 3):

```
var query = from x in class1Enumerable
            where x.class2Instance != null
            where x.class2Instance.class3Instance != null
            where x.class2Instance.class3Instance.id == yourId
            select x;
```